Creating a SpatRaster with Multiple Binned AQUA-MODIS (NetCDF) Files with the Function terra::rast() in R
Issue
I downloaded AQUA-MODIS netcdf files (total = 3422) for chlorophyll-a from the Earthdata website from 2012 to 2024 for The Northern Red Sea, Egypt.
I need to:

Stack all the 3422 AQUA MODIS netcdf in the function terra::rast() (or equivalent) to create a SpatRaster to calculate the mean chlorophyll-a levels of all files.

I have tried using packages such as ncdf4, terra, raster, and RNetCDF without any success (see my efforts below). I've also tried looking for solutions on Stackoverflow and did some troubleshooting with suggestions from ChatGPT and nothing has worked. I really don't understand how find a solution.
Many thanks if anyone can help.
Here's the manifest.txt link to get the data (expires Oct 22nd 2024)
https://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi/getfile/requested_files_2.tar?h=ocdist410&p=/data1/d0703031e30f7f6f/requested_files
Read the files into R:
 library(terra)
 library(ncdf4)
 library(raster)
 library(RNetCDF)

#Start the file path to all the netcdf files as a variable 'folder'
folder<-"~/Documents/GIS_Data/CHL-A/"

#Make a list of all the files within the folder 
files <-list.files(folder, pattern='*.nc', full.names ="TRUE")

Loop through all the file paths and the AQUA MODIS netcdf files to gain access to them:
for (file in files) {
     nc=open.nc(file)
     print.nc(nc)
}

Contents of one of the AQUA MODIS files
netcdf netcdf4 {

// global attributes:
        NC_CHAR :product_name = "AQUA_MODIS.20221217.L3b.DAY.CHL.x.nc" ;
        NC_CHAR :title = "MODIS Level-3 Binned Data" ;
        NC_CHAR :instrument = "MODIS" ;
        NC_CHAR :platform = "Aqua" ;
        NC_CHAR :temporal_range = "day" ;
        NC_INT :start_orbit_number = 109682 ;
        NC_INT :end_orbit_number = 109698 ;
        NC_CHAR :date_created = "2024289095750000" ;
        NC_CHAR :processing_version = "unspecified" ;
        NC_CHAR :source = "satellite observations from MODIS-Aqua" ;
        NC_CHAR :history = "/sdps/sdpsoper/Science/OCSSW/DEVEL/bin/l3bin ifile=AQUA_MODIS.20221217.L3b.DAY.CHL.nc ofile=AQUA_MODIS.20221217.L3b.DAY.CHL.x.nc latnorth=37.0000 latsouth=5.1000 lonwest=26.7200 loneast=54.1400" ;
        NC_CHAR :time_coverage_start = "2022-12-17T00:25:01.000Z" ;
        NC_CHAR :time_coverage_end = "2022-12-18T02:59:59.000Z" ;
        NC_FLOAT :northernmost_latitude = 36.8958320617676 ;
        NC_FLOAT :southernmost_latitude = 5.10416650772095 ;
        NC_FLOAT :easternmost_longitude = 50.6941337585449 ;
        NC_FLOAT :westernmost_longitude = 26.7268047332764 ;
        NC_DOUBLE :geospatial_lat_max = 36.8958320617676 ;
        NC_DOUBLE :geospatial_lat_min = 5.10416650772095 ;
        NC_DOUBLE :geospatial_lon_max = 50.6941337585449 ;
        NC_DOUBLE :geospatial_lon_min = 26.7268047332764 ;
        NC_CHAR :geospatial_lat_units = "degrees_north" ;
        NC_CHAR :geospatial_lon_units = "degrees_east" ;
        NC_CHAR :geospatial_lat_resolution = "4.638312 km" ;
        NC_CHAR :geospatial_lon_resolution = "4.638312 km" ;
        NC_CHAR :spatialResolution = "4.638312 km" ;
        NC_INT :data_bins = 31421 ;
        NC_FLOAT :percent_data_bins = 0.132233932614326 ;
        NC_CHAR :units = "chlor_a:mg m^-3" ;
        NC_CHAR :binning_scheme = "Integerized Sinusoidal Grid" ;
        NC_CHAR :project = "Ocean Biology Processing Group (NASA/GSFC/OBPG)" ;
        NC_CHAR :institution = "NASA Goddard Space Flight Center, Ocean Ecology Laboratory, Ocean Biology Processing Group" ;
        NC_CHAR :standard_name_vocabulary = "CF Standard Name Table v36" ;
        NC_CHAR :Conventions = "CF-1.6 ACDD-1.3" ;
        NC_CHAR :naming_authority = "gov.nasa.gsfc.sci.oceandata" ;
        NC_CHAR :id = "AQUA_MODIS.20221217.L3b.DAY.CHL.x.nc/L3/AQUA_MODIS.20221217.L3b.DAY.CHL.x.nc" ;
        NC_CHAR :license = "https://science.nasa.gov/earth-science/earth-science-data/data-information-policy/" ;
        NC_CHAR :creator_name = "NASA/GSFC/OBPG" ;
        NC_CHAR :publisher_name = "NASA/GSFC/OBPG" ;
        NC_CHAR :creator_email = "data@oceancolor.gsfc.nasa.gov" ;
        NC_CHAR :publisher_email = "data@oceancolor.gsfc.nasa.gov" ;
        NC_CHAR :creator_url = "https://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov" ;
        NC_CHAR :publisher_url = "https://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov" ;
        NC_CHAR :processing_level = "L3 Binned" ;
        NC_CHAR :cdm_data_type = "point" ;
        NC_CHAR :keywords_vocabulary = "NASA Global Change Master Directory (GCMD) Science Keywords" ;
        NC_CHAR :keywords = "Earth Science > Oceans > Ocean Chemistry > Pigments > Chlorophyll; Earth Science > Oceans > Ocean Chemistry > Chlorophyll" ;

group: level-3_binned_data {
  dimensions:
    binListDim = UNLIMITED ; // (31421 currently)
    binDataDim = UNLIMITED ; // (31421 currently)
    binIndexDim = UNLIMITED ; // (4320 currently)
  types:
    compound binListType {
      NC_UINT bin_num ;
      NC_SHORT nobs ;
      NC_SHORT nscenes ;
      NC_FLOAT weights ;
      NC_FLOAT time_rec ;
    }; // binListType
    compound binDataType {
      NC_FLOAT sum ;
      NC_FLOAT sum_squared ;
    }; // binDataType
    compound binIndexType {
      NC_UINT start_num ;
      NC_UINT begin ;
      NC_UINT extent ;
      NC_UINT max ;
    }; // binIndexType
  variables:
    binListType BinList(binListDim) ;
    binDataType chlor_a(binDataDim) ;
    binIndexType BinIndex(binIndexDim) ;
  } // group level-3_binned_data

group: processing_control {

  // group attributes:
        NC_CHAR :software_name = "L3BIN" ;
        NC_CHAR :software_version = "5.14" ;
        NC_CHAR :input_sources = "AQUA_MODIS.20221217.L3b.DAY.CHL.nc" ;
        NC_CHAR :l2_flag_names = "ATMFAIL,LAND,HILT,HISATZEN,STRAYLIGHT,CLDICE,COCCOLITH,LOWLW,CHLWARN,CHLFAIL,NAVWARN,MAXAERITER,ATMWARN,HISOLZEN,NAVFAIL,FILTER,HIGLINT" ;

  group: input_parameters {

    // group attributes:
            NC_CHAR :infile = "AQUA_MODIS.20221217.L3b.DAY.CHL.nc" ;
            NC_CHAR :ofile = "AQUA_MODIS.20221217.L3b.DAY.CHL.x.nc" ;
            NC_CHAR :pfile = "AQUA_MODIS.20221217.L3b.DAY.CHL.x.nc" ;
            NC_CHAR :oformat = "netCDF4" ;
            NC_CHAR :syear = "9999" ;
            NC_CHAR :eyear = "9999" ;
            NC_CHAR :sday = "1970001" ;
            NC_CHAR :eday = "2038018" ;
            NC_CHAR :sorbit = "-1" ;
            NC_CHAR :eorbit = "-1" ;
            NC_CHAR :out_parm = ":DEFAULT:" ;
            NC_CHAR :processing_version = "unspecified" ;
            NC_CHAR :reduce_fac = "1" ;
            NC_CHAR :resolve = "" ;
            NC_CHAR :merged = "" ;
            NC_CHAR :loneast = "54.139999" ;
            NC_CHAR :lonwest = "26.719999" ;
            NC_CHAR :latnorth = "37.000000" ;
            NC_CHAR :latsouth = "5.100000" ;
            NC_CHAR :verbose = "0" ;
            NC_CHAR :unit_wgt = "0" ;
            NC_CHAR :median = "0" ;
            NC_CHAR :deflate = "5" ;
            NC_CHAR :composite_prod = "" ;
            NC_CHAR :composite_scheme = "" ;
            NC_CHAR :doi = "" ;
    } // group input_parameters
  } // group processing_control
}

Attempts to Stack the netcdf files:
Attempt 1:
chla1<-terra::rast(files)

Error Message
Error: [rast] cannot open this file as a SpatRaster: /Documents/GIS_Data/CHL-A/AQUA_MODIS.20120101.L3b.DAY.CHL.x.nc
In addition: Warning message:
`Documents/GIS_Data/CHL-A/AQUA_MODIS.20120101.L3b.DAY.CHL.x.nc' not recognized as a supported file format. (GDAL error 4)

Attempt 2:
chla1<-terra::rast(nc)

Error Message:
Error in methods::as(x, "SpatRaster") : 
  no method or default for coercing “NetCDF” to “SpatRaster”

Attempt 3:
chl4<-raster::stack(files)

Error Message
Error in ncvar_type_to_string(rv$precint) : 
Error, unrecognized type code of variable supplied: -1

Screenshot of my R Environment

Screenshot of some of my files in my directory


I think if you incorporate @LTyrone 's !That worked part of 'approaches tried based on comments' in your above, drop the screen shot of files, make note of the version of @Patrick ncdfCF that finally resolved or mitigated, it might further reopening process. It would also allow @LTyrone to present his work around as answer, even at Patrick was updating his code for this particular contingency (or advocating for such a change elsewhere). I think a roadmap for these netcdf vagaries is important as other researchers as yourself will crash upon these shoals and case for re-opening to resolution.

These are "level-3 binned" data. That means that the data are packed by latitudinal rows and longitudinal bins per row. Neither terra nor raster will read that, and even ncdf4 reports an error upon opening the file. The only package that I know of that will open the files without error is ncdfCF but even that won't recognise the data set contained in each file. The below function is built on top of ncdfCF to read L5b data; you need the dev version from GitHub for this to work. Please note that the code is largely untested; it is also not very performant but it will get the job done.
#' Read a MODIS level-3 binned (L3b) file
#'
#' This function will read a MODIS L3b file and return a `CFData` object with
#' the data in physical units and registered to a latitude-longitude coordinate
#' system on an authalic sphere of radius 6,378,145 m.
#'
#' This is very crude code to test the processing of L3b files. There are no
#' significant checks to capture and correct for edge cases or other potential
#' problems. The code is also not very performant, emphasis is on proof-of-concept.
#' Report any problems in the GitHub issue dedicated to building this
#' functionality into ncdfCF: https://github.com/pvanlaake/ncdfCF/issues/4.
#'
#' Once tested, this code is likely to be merged into ncdfCF.
#'
#' This code requires version 0.2.1 or higher of ncdfCF and library abind.
#'
#' @param fn Fully qualified name of the MODIS L3b netCDF file.
#' @param aoi Subset of data to extract, vector of four values minimum and
#' maximum longitude, minimum and maximum latitude.
#'
#' @return A `CFData` object.
#' @export
#'
#' @noRd
read_l5b <- function(fn, aoi = c(-180, 180, -90, 90)) {
  require(abind)

  ds <- open_ncdf(fn)
  if (length(names(ds)))
    stop("This file has recognized data variables. It is probably not a L3b formatted file. Quitting.")

  units <- ds$root$attribute("units")
  if (nzchar(units)) {
    units <- strsplit(units, ":")[[1L]]
    variable <- units[1L]
    units <- units[2L]
  } else stop("Required attribute 'units' not found. Quitting.")

  grp <- ds$root$subgroups[["level-3_binned_data"]]
  if (is.null(grp) || length(names(grp$NCvars)) != 3L)
    stop("This file does not have the required netCDF variables for L3b data. Quitting.")

  # Read the data
  h <- grp$handle
  binList <- RNetCDF::var.get.nc(h, "BinList")
  binIndex <- RNetCDF::var.get.nc(h, "BinIndex")
  binData <- RNetCDF::var.get.nc(h, variable)

  # Calculate global center lat-long and bounds
  numRows <- length(binIndex$start_num)
  lat <- (1:numRows - 0.5) * 180 / numRows - 90
  lat_bnds <- 0:numRows * 180 / numRows - 90

  lon_bins <- binIndex$max[numRows * 0.5]
  lon <- (1:lon_bins - 0.5) * 360 / lon_bins - 180
  lon_bnds <- 0:lon_bins * 360 / lon_bins - 180

  # Get the binned data in rows
  data_row <- findInterval(binList$bin_num, binIndex$start_num)
  data_row_bin <- as.integer(binList$bin_num - binIndex$start_num[data_row]) + 1L

  # Subset the latitude
  startRow <- floor((aoi[3L] + 90) * numRows / 180) + 1L
  endRow <- floor((aoi[4L] + 90) * numRows / 180)
  aoi_rows <- endRow - startRow + 1L
  lat <- lat[startRow:endRow]
  lat_bnds <- lat_bnds[startRow:(endRow+1L)]

  # Subset the longitude
  startBin <- floor((aoi[1L] + 180) * lon_bins / 360) + 1L
  endBin <- floor((aoi[2L] + 180) * lon_bins / 360)
  aoi_bins <- endBin - startBin + 1L
  lon <- lon[startBin:endBin]
  lon_bnds <- lon_bnds[startBin:(endBin+1L)]

  l <- lapply(startRow:endRow, function(r) {
    out <- rep(NA_real_, lon_bins)
    idx <- which(data_row == r)
    if (!length(idx)) return(out[startBin:endBin])

    d <- binData$sum[idx] / binList$weights[idx]   # The data of the physical property
    b <- data_row_bin[idx]                         # The bins to put the data in

    # Expand to lon_bins grid cells
    allocate <- ceiling(1:lon_bins * binIndex$max[r] / lon_bins)

    # Allocate the data to the expanded grid cells
    for (bin in seq_along(b))
      out[which(allocate == b[bin])] <- d[bin]

    out[startBin:endBin]
  })
  data <- abind::abind(l, along = 2)

  out_group <- makeMemoryGroup(-1L, "Memory_group", "/Memory_group", paste("Regridding L5b file", ds$name),
                               paste0(format(Sys.time(), "%FT%T%z"), " R package ncdfCF(", packageVersion("ncdfCF"), ")::read_l5b()"))

  axis_lon <- makeLongitudeAxis(-1L, "longitude", out_group, aoi_bins, lon, rbind(lon_bnds[-aoi_bins], lon_bnds[-1L]), "degrees_east")
  axis_lat <- makeLatitudeAxis(-1L, "latitude", out_group, aoi_rows, lat, rbind(lat_bnds[-aoi_rows], lat_bnds[-1L]), "degrees_north")

  atts <- ds$attributes()
  atts <- atts[!(atts$name %in% c("data_bins", "percent_data_bins", "binning_scheme")), ]
  atts[atts$name == "title", "value"] <- paste0(atts[atts$name == "title", ]$value[[1L]], " - regridded")
  atts[atts$name == "units", "value"] <- units
  atts[atts$name == "processing_level", "value"] <- paste0(atts[atts$name == "processing_level", ]$value[[1L]], "; regridded to lat-long using ncdfCF::read_l5b()")

  crs <- 'GEOGCRS["Unknown",DATUM["unknown",ELLIPSOID["unknown",6378145,0,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],CS[ellipsoidal,2],AXIS["Geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,ORDER[1]],AXIS["Geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,ORDER[2]],ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]]'
  CFData$new(variable, out_group, data, list(longitude = axis_lon, latitude = axis_lat), crs, atts)
}

The function returns a CFData instance which can be used for further processing. Reading and plotting a file looks like this:
(chlor_a <- read_l5b("/my_data/AQUA_MODIS.20030101.L3b.DAY.CHL.nc"))
#> <Data> chlor_a 
#> 
#> Values: [0.003207558 ... 86.26505] 
#>     NA: 34481801 (92.4%)
#> 
#> Axes:
#>  id axis name      length values                    
#>  -1 X    longitude 8640   [-179.97917 ... 179.97917]
#>  -1 Y    latitude  4320   [-89.979167 ... 89.979167]
plot(chlor_a$terra())
plot(rnaturalearth::ne_coastline(), add = TRUE)


To do your analysis with all 3,422 files you need to run the above function for each of them. From the resulting CFData objects you can get access to the data with the CFData::array() method. You can then join them into an array with the abind::abind() function  and then apply(<data array>, 1:2, mean, na.rm = TRUE) to get your desired result.
The code also works if your data is a subset for the northern Red Sea only. In this case you should call the function like chlor_a <- read_l5b("/my_data/AQUA_MODIS.20030101.L3b.DAY.CHL.nc", aio <- c(26, 55, 5, 37)), using your preferred extent.

Thank you so much for explaining what the problem is and why none of the traditional methods are not working, I've been going crazy with this. I ran the code (vars <- chl$root$unused()) and I got this error message 'Error: attempt to apply non-function'. Would you know how to fix this? Many thanks for your time, I really do appreciate it!

Hi Alice, you should download the development version from GitHub:
devtools::install_github("pvanlaake/ncdfCF"). First do install.packages("devtools") if you don't have that installed already.

Aha! I did this and the package downloaded, no issue but I still got the same error. Not sure!

I just checked ChatGPT about this error: It said:The "attempt to apply non-function" error in R typically occurs when you try to use a variable as if it were a function. This can happen if you mistakenly use parentheses on a variable that is not a function, such as a vector or a list. For example, if you have a variable that holds a data type and you try to call it like a function, R will throw this error

This line of code is a list 'files <-list.files(folder, pattern='*.nc', full.names ="TRUE")'. Perhaps this is the problem

Very curious as well as netcdf are curious, I find I have ncdfCF version 0.1.1, and now a use case! Better still would be when to use ncdf x, y, z...tools.

@Patrick How did you run the line (vars <- chl$root$unused())' and extract that information? I've tried to manipulate it by changing the brackets and I either get an output of NULL or Error: attempt to apply non-function. I've downloaded the package so that's not issue. What are we doing differently. Many thanks if you can enlighten me. Many thanks again

@LTyrone Thank you for your suggestions. I tried to use the code that you with the first line subgroup to try and extract information on the variables and the dimensions. I ran them and I got Error: object 'subgroups' not found'. Does 'subgroup' mean I need to use information from the printed output in the solution above as subgroup? Would it be posible to please provide more infomation about 'subgroup'? I'm completely lost here. I'm so happy Patrick has provided information about the problem

@AliceHobbs - my bad, run subgroups <- nc$root$subgroups, then run the other code. Apologies

This is interesting: If you run vars<-subgroups[["level-3_binned_data"]]$NCvars
and then d <- var.get.nc(vars[[1]]$group$handle, vars[[1]]$name), it prints out $bin_num, $nobs, $nscenes, $weights, and $time_rec

@LTyrone When I ran this code 'subgroups[["level-3_binned_data"]]$NCdim', I got a NULL output. Is the variable $weights the chlorophyll-a data?

@AliceHobbs - 1) create your files object 2) nc <- open_ncdf(files[1]) 3) subgroups <- nc$root$subgroups 4) subgroups[["level-3_binned_data"]]$NCdims If that doesn't work, I can't say what your issue is. Good luck!

@LTyrone Wonderful! That worked! At this point, I think you deserve to be an author on my poster at the conference I'm presenting at in 3 weeks. The pressure of a deadline

@AliceHobbs and @LTyrone, I think GitHub played a caching trick on you. The patch with the unused() method was uploaded before I answered the question but it appears you have an older patch. Can you try again now that it has been up a little while longer? The patch has id bc9ffc1, the code is in R/NCGroup.R lines 197-210, for your reference. Updated my answer and suggest we move to an ncdfCF issue where there are better options for iterating towards. solution.

@Patrick I ran your code again with the unused() method and I still go the same error message Error: attempt to apply non-function. Would you mind giving me more instructions to use version with the new id bc9ffc1? That would be amazing as I don't really understand patches too well

This question as been closed! I don't understand because I think my aims and objectives are quite clear and this question is important because there isn't any content to help people in this same position. I've voted for it to be reopened

Hi Alice, looking into it. In the mean time, let's continue the discussion on GitHub. Do you have an account there? If not, just sign up and look at the issue there. Given your conference is in three weeks, perhaps you should look into other software to read the L3b data (I would not know which one) while we try to implement this for R.

@Patrick - it was a caching issue, working now.

@LTyrone - Ok, great to hear. I have looked at the binning scheme yesterday and today will be coding a function. It appears to be less demanding than expected but the devil is always in the detail!

AliceHobbs and @LTyrone: I have updated my answer with a function to read and process L5b files.

@Patrick - added to your GitHub thread with a link to a .nc from the OP's dataset and some explanatory notes.

Answer updated, code now also subsetting to any specific area of interest.
